# Smoke not showing in Cycles Render

Tags: rendering, shaders, physics, smoke-simulation, mantaflow

The smoke effect in my scene randomly stopped showing up in renders. I'm not sure what's changed

1. Show in renders visibility is set to on
2. The smoke has a material
3. There appears to be no problem with the shader. Even when I detach all of the nodes and just have a principled volume shader, it doesn't show.
4. when I turn up the density in the principled shader, it makes no difference.
5. the smoke will show up in a Eevee render, but not in cycles, which is what I'm using.

Blender file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EO4vlfcATdU7qs_05VUI9W-FPTmYBztT/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ray visibility settings for the smoke domain were all deactivated.

I unchecked them because the smoke domain appeared to be casting unwanted shadows.